# Write a query identifying the type of each record in the TRIANGLES table using its three side lengths

Tags: sql-server

Write a query identifying the type of each record in the TRIANGLES table using its three side lengths. Output one of the following statements for each record in the table:

Equilateral: It's a triangle with  sides of equal length.
Isosceles: It's a triangle with  sides of equal length.
Scalene: It's a triangle with  sides of differing lengths.
Not A Triangle: The given values of A, B, and C don't form a triangle.

Comment: Can you please paste the code which shows what you have tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you just copy pasted the question from somewhere. Please provide the code what you already have tried and explain issue are you facing?

Comment: You posted the question and your own answer within the same minute. This is not a personal blogging platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN ((a.A + a.B) <= a.C) 
              THEN 'Not A Triangle'
            ELSE
            CASE
            WHEN ((a.A = a.B) AND (a.B = a.C))
               THEN 'Equilateral'
               ELSE 
               CASE                
                 WHEN ((a.A = a.B) or (a.B = a.C) or (a.A = a.C))
                     THEN 'Isosceles'
                     ELSE 
                        CASE
                            WHEN ((a.A != a.B) AND (a.B != a.C) AND (a.A != a.C))
                                THEN 'Scalene '
                            END
                 END
          END
       END 
FROM TRIANGLES a;
```

Comment: you should delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

short version:

```
select case
when ((t.A+t.B)<=t.C)
    then 'Not A Triangle'
else
    case 
        when (t.A = t.B) and (t.A = t.C) then 'Equilateral'
    else
        case 
            when (t.A = t.B) or (t.A=t.C) or (t.C=t.B) then 'Isosceles'
        else
            'Scalene '
        end
    end
end 
from TRIANGLES as t
```

Answer (score 0):

HackeRrank MySQL - Type of Triangle Quiz!

```
select case
when ((t.A+t.B)<=t.c) then 'Not A Triangle'
else
    case
    when (t.A=t.B) and (t.B=t.c) then 'Equilateral'
    else
        case
        when (t.A = t.B) or (t.A = t.C) or (t.B = t.C) then 'Isosceles'
        else
            'Scalene'
        end
    end
end
from triangles as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
CASE
WHEN (A=B AND B=C AND C=A) THEN 'Equilateral'
WHEN (A=B OR A=C OR B=C) AND (A + B > C AND B+C > A AND C+A > B) THEN     'Isosceles'
WHEN A<>B<>C AND (A + B > C AND B+C > A AND C+A > B) THEN 'Scalene'
ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END
FROM TRIANGLES;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT

CASE

```
WHEN (A=B AND B=C AND C=A) THEN 'Equilateral'
WHEN (A=B OR A=C OR B=C) AND (A + B > C AND B+C > A AND C+A > B) THEN     'Isosceles'
WHEN A<>B<>C AND (A + B > C AND B+C > A AND C+A > B) THEN 'Scalene'
ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
```

END

FROM TRIANGLES;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(CASE 
WHEN (A=B AND B=C AND C=A) THEN 'Equilateral'
WHEN (A=B OR A=C OR B=C) AND (A + B > C AND B + C > A AND C + A > B) THEN 'Isosceles'
WHEN (A <> B AND B <>C AND C <> A) AND (A + B > C AND B + C > A AND C + A > B) THEN 'Scalene'
ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
 END)
FROM TRIANGLES;
--THIS WORKS FOR DB2 DATABASES AND SCALENCE CONDITION COULD BE EQUIVALENT TO A<>B<>C
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
CASE
    WHEN (A+B > C AND B+C > A AND A+C > B) THEN
    (CASE
        WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN "Equilateral"
        WHEN A = B OR B = C OR A = C THEN "Isosceles"
        WHEN A != B AND B != C AND A != C THEN "Scalene"
    END)
    ELSE "Not A Triangle"
END
FROM TRIANGLES
```

First, check if the value can form a triangle then check which type it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    
case 
    
when (a.A+a.B<=a.C) then 'Not A Triangle'
    
when (a.A = a.B) and (a.A = a.C) then 'Equilateral'
    
when (a.A = a.B) or (a.B=a.C) or (a.C=a.A)  then 'Isosceles'
    
else 'Scalene'
    
end

from TRIANGLES a;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This is a code-only answer on the one hand and it's incorrect on the other hand. For example, if `a.A` is greater than `a.B+a.C`, then it would yield either Isosceles or Scalene, depending on whether `a.B` and `a.C` are equal, instead of the correct 'Not a Triangle'.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all we need to know when we know for sure that A, B and C cannot form a triangle. It is the case when the sum of any two lengths of the sides is lesser than or equal than the third, that is:

> A + B <= C
>
> OR
>
> A + C <= B
>
> OR
>
> B + C <= A

The reason is that if A = B + C, then A is of the combined length of B and C and thusly they can only form a collinear line, but not a triangle. If A is even lass than that, then they self-contradict on an Euclidean plane.

Otherwise, we are interested whether all the length are equal with each other, or only one of them.

```
SELECT A, B, C,
CASE
    WHEN A >= B + C OR
         B >= A + C OR
         C >= A + B
    THEN 'Not a Triangle'
    WHEN A = B AND
         B = C
    THEN 'Equilateral'
    WHEN A = B OR
         A = C OR
         B = C
    THEN 'Isosceles'
    ELSE 'Scalene'
END AS Type
FROM triangles
```

Note that we are making full use of the fact that a latter `when` is logically equivalent to an `else if`, that is, it will only be evaluated if the earlier cases were all false.

Example:

```
select case when 1=1 then 'a' when 2=2 then 'b' end;
```

will yield 'a' because 1=1, even though 2=2 is also true.